# Alinhamento Gif Loading

Tags: html, css, sass

Olá,

Tenho o seguinte código:

https://jsbin.com/jojukiseze/1/edit?html,css,output

Estou tentando alinhá-lo para que fique centralizado na tela independente do tamanho da tela ou orientação (seja um celular na vertical ou horizontal), porém sem sucesso.

Alguma sugestão?

Obrigado!

Comment: Coloque o html e css referente ao que está perguntando....

Comment: está tudo no link @MagicHat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por `position: absolute` você pode resolver botando 0 em todos os lados. Seu CSS ficaria assim:

```
.ajax-spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 225px;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito Leon, simples e eficiente, muito obrigado!!

Comment: Que bom que ajudou! :)

Comment: fico bom mesmo...

Answer (score 2):

Bom uma solução seria com Flexbox:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="mask-loading">
    <figure class="alinha-loading">
      <img class="ajax-spinner img-responsive" src="https://mir-s3-cdn-cf.behance.net/project_modules/disp/585d0331234507.564a1d239ac5e.gif" alt="carregando...">
    </figure>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
<style>
.mask-loading{
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 100;
 background-color: #000;
 opacity: 0.8;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.alinha-loading{
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 225px; 
 opacity: 1;
    max-width: 50%;
  
}
</style>
```